# DAX/POWERBI : count tickets attached to an item and all its child items

Tags: dax

I am new to DAX and PowerBI and have a problem to write DAX formulas for my case:
I have two tables: Assets and Tickets. Each have an Id, and the Assets have a ParentAssetId (can be 0 or None).
In a DAX expression: I would like to count (and list) all the tickets attached to an Asset and its children.

I tried this way but without success:

```
nbChildTickets = 
VAR mykey = 
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Assets[AssetKey] )
VAR mypar = 
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Assets[ParentId] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTX(Tickets, Tickets[TicketKey]),
        FILTER(Tickets, RELATED(Assets[ParentId]) = mykey)
    )
```

[The Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3ZvP.jpg) and [the Canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDD03.jpg)

It is the asset table which contains both the AssetKey and the ParentId colums.

Have any idea or tuto to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A question, are these tables already related? In case they are, it seems that you wouldn't need a measure like that to get the count of # of tickets by asset and its parent. I would do it in the next two ways. Supposing you need it in a table:

**Option 1.**

1. Create a simple count measure to get the number of tickets in Tickets table, it could be something like `Number of Tickets = COUNTROWS('Tickets')`
2. Drag a table to the canvas.
3. Add to the table Assets and its children columns, finally add your new measure to the table

**Option 2. In case each ticket has an ID.**

1. Drag a table to the canvas.
2. Add to the table Assets and its children columns. Also add your tickets Id.
3. At Fields section (where you drag and drop your columns, right click and select the *Count* option.
4. Done

Remember, it is important that your both tables are already related to work. Otherwise Power BI will not know how to calculate and displays this combination of data for you.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the clues. I added a copy of my tables and canvas in the first post. But my Assets have only AssetsId and ParentId. No direct child stuff. I managed to get the count of tickets for each Asset, but not for the Assest and its children assets. Note that the Children Assets are in the same table as the parents : it is the Assets table.

Comment: As I have no direct child information or specific table, I didn't not managed to do the 'children column' steps you are refering to. Have you any more hints for my case ?

Answer (score 0):

First create two relationships between **Assets** and **Ticket** table. One relationship will be active (one to  many) on column **AssetKey** Column.

Second relationship will be Inactive. Asset[AssetKey] = Ticket[ParentID]

Now use the below Measures -

```
Number Of Tickets = COUNT(Tickets[TicketKey])

Number of Child = CALCULATE(COUNT(Tickets[AssetKey]),USERELATIONSHIP(Asset[AssetKey],Tickets[ParentId]))
```

Relationship diagram is in below image :

[image]

Output is mentioned below:

[image]

The blank row can be eliminated from visual filters :

[image]